# RxJS finalize operator vs tap({ finalize: () => {} })

Tags: rxjs, tap, finalize

Is there any difference between A and B? Are there any cases where one would behave differently than the other?

**A)**

```
observableHere
    .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
            // Do stuff here
        })
    )
```

**B)**

```
observableHere
    .pipe(
        tap({
            finalize: () => {
                // Do stuff here
            })
        })
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tap lets you hook into a bunch of events on the source observable

```ts
interface TapObserver<T>: {
   next: (value: T) => void;
   error: (err: any) => void;
   complete: () => void;
   subscribe: () => void;
   unsubscribe: () => void;
   finalize: () => void;
}
```

If you're producing side effects for an observable's various emissions, it might be easier to group them all together in a single `TapObserver`. Otherwise, just using the finalize operator is probably clearer.

---

> Are there any cases where one would behave differently than the other?

They shouldn't behave any differently.

Comment: As mentioned by Matthieu below, if `finalize` exists in both places, tap's `finalize` would be executed first.

Answer (score 0):

Finalize in tap makes absolutly no sense to me.

The only difference is that it will be called before the final finalize.